# Selecting number of hours between start time and end time raises an alert regardless of selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Our app has time ranges, Start Time and End Time.

Users must select a minimum of 4 hours before they are allowed to continue processing their requests.

So far, it doesn't matter what time range a user selects, an alert is raised.

For instance, if a user selects start time of 07:00:00 and end time of 12:00:00, no alert should be raised and the user should proceed with rest of request.

Any ideas what needs to change with code below?

Thanks a lot in advance

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/datePicker.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 


  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
       $(window).load(function () {
           //Attach click event to button
           $('#Button1').on('click', function () {
               //Get Values from dropdownlist
               var sHour = $('#startHour').val(),
                eHour = $('#endHour').val();

               //create date format from dropdownlist selected values 
               var theDate = $('#<%= txtDate.ClientID%>').val();
               var timeStart = new Date(theDate + sHour).getHours();
               var timeEnd = new Date(theDate + eHour).getHours();

               //Calulate the time difference
               var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;

               //Check if hour difference is less than 4 hours and show the message accordingly
               if (hourDiff < 4) {
                   alert("A mininum of 4 hours is required!");
               }
           });
       });//]]>  

</script>
                       <td align="right">
                        <span id="lblDate">Date</span>
                       </td>
                       <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                       </td>
                       <td align="right">
                        <span id="lblStarTime">Start Time</span>
                       </td>
                       <td align="left">
                       <asp:DropDownList id="startHour" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="07:00:00">07</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="08:00:00">08</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="09:00:00">09</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="10:00:00">10</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="11:00:00">11</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="00:00:00">12</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="01:00:00">01</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="02:00:00">02</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="03:00:00">03</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="04:00:00">04</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="05:00:00">05</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="06:00:00">06</asp:ListItem>
                       </asp:DropDownList>

                        <asp:DropDownList id="startMinutes" runat="server">
                 <asp:ListItem Value="00">00</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Value="15">15</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Value="30">30</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Value="45">45</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                       <asp:DropDownList id="startAmPm" runat="server">
                 <asp:ListItem Value="AM">AM</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="PM">PM</asp:ListItem>
                       </asp:DropDownList>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                      <td align="right">
                       <span id="lbEndTime">End Time</span>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left">
                       <asp:DropDownList id="endHour" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="07:00:00">07</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="08:00:00">08</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="09:00:00">09</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="10:00:00">10</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="11:00:00">11</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="00:00:00">12</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="01:00:00">01</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="02:00:00">02</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="03:00:00">03</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="04:00:00">04</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="05:00:00">05</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="06:00:00">06</asp:ListItem>
                       </asp:DropDownList>

                       <asp:DropDownList id="endMinutes" runat="server">
                 <asp:ListItem Value="00">00</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Value="15">15</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Value="30">30</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Value="45">45</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                       <asp:DropDownList id="endAmPm" runat="server">
                 <asp:ListItem Value="AM">AM</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="PM">PM</asp:ListItem>
                       </asp:DropDownList>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                    </div>
                   </table>

                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: I don't see that you adding AM/PM to the string you are passing to the Date() constructor.

Comment: What is it that you expect `theDate + sHour` to look like?

Comment: i suggest validating the time difference on serverside, not with javascript. people could just open dev console and bypass your validation

Comment: @JustinRusso, Eugine, Banana, Pointy, thank you guys for the prompt response. 

I have updated my post with the versions of JQuery I am using.

Eugene, I didn't think I needed to add the AM/PM. It was there to guy the user to make time selection AM or PM. 

Pointy, we expect something like 07/01/2014 07:00:00 to 07/01/2014 11:00:00 or something to that effect. It is a daily event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how you are creating your `Date` variables. You need a space between your date and your time.

**Update:**

Like what Matthew at Critical Cognition and some others have mentioned, you will want to add the AM/PM values. That way something like 2:00pm gives an hour value of 14, rather than 2.

```
var sAmPm = $('#startAmPm').val();
var eAmPm = $('#endAmPm').val();
var timeStart = new Date(theDate + ' ' + sHour + ' ' + sAmPm).getHours();
var timeEnd = new Date(theDate + ' ' + eHour + ' ' + eAmPm).getHours();
```

Comment: WOW, @BubbleHearth, you are absolutely right!

That fixed it.

Thanks so much and thanks to all of you that responded.

Comment: This will create a valid Date object but it will not calculate the difference between the 2 times correctly.  You need to add AM/PM to get the 24 hour clock.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated the entire thing in JSFiddle, and it works as expected.  Might I suggest you use my method for getting the current date? I think the problem was with the spaces I added to the Date concatenations.  As mentioned in the other answer by "BubbleHeart."

http://jsfiddle.net/c5r28/

```
       //Attach click event to button
       $('#Button1').on('click', function () {
           var currentDate = new Date();
           //Get Values from dropdownlist
           var sHour = $('#startHour').val(),
            eHour = $('#endHour').val();

           //create date format from dropdownlist selected values 
           var theDate = (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + currentDate.getDate() + '/' + currentDate.getFullYear();
           var timeStart = new Date(theDate + ' ' + sHour).getHours();
           var timeEnd = new Date(theDate  + ' ' + eHour).getHours();

           //Calulate the time difference
           var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;

           //Check if hour difference is less than 4 hours and show the message accordingly
           if (hourDiff < 4) {
               alert("A mininum of 4 hours is required!");
           }
       });
```

Comment: thanks. BubbleHeart was a bit faster and yes, what you did differently was add spaces between theDate and hours. 

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.  First, add a space when constructing your Date object.  Second, you need to take into account AM and PM.  Third, only pull the hours from the hour box, not a full hour:minute:seconds.  Working code:

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
       $(window).load(function () {
           //Attach click event to button
           $('#Button1').on('click', function () {
               //Get Values from dropdownlist
               var sHour = $('#startHour').val();
               var sMinutes = $('#startMinutes').val();
               var sAmPm = $('#startAmPm').val();

               var eHour = $('#endHour').val();
               var eMinutes = $('#endMinutes').val();
               var eAmPm = $('#endAmPm').val();

               //create date format from dropdownlist selected values 
               var theDate = $('#<%= txtDate.ClientID%>').val();
           var timeStart = new Date(theDate + ' ' + sHour + ':' + sMinutes + ' ' + sAmPm).getHours();
           var timeEnd = new Date(theDate + ' ' + eHour + ':' + eMinutes + ' ' + eAmPm).getHours();

           //Calulate the time difference
           var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;

           //Check if hour difference is less than 4 hours and show the message accordingly
           if (hourDiff < 4) {
               alert("A mininum of 4 hours is required!");
           }
       });
   });//]]>  

</script>
                   <td align="right">
                    <span id="lblDate">Date</span>
                   </td>
                   <td align="left">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                   </td>
                   <td align="right">
                    <span id="lblStarTime">Start Time</span>
                   </td>
                   <td align="left">
                   <asp:DropDownList id="startHour" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="07">07</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="08">08</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="09">09</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="11">11</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="12">12</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="01">01</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="02">02</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="03">03</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="04">04</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="05">05</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="06">06</asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:DropDownList>

                    <asp:DropDownList id="startMinutes" runat="server">
             <asp:ListItem Value="00">00</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="15">15</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="30">30</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="45">45</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

                   <asp:DropDownList id="startAmPm" runat="server">
             <asp:ListItem Value="AM">AM</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="PM">PM</asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:DropDownList>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td align="right">
                   <span id="lbEndTime">End Time</span>
                  </td>
                  <td align="left">
                   <asp:DropDownList id="endHour" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="07">07</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="08">08</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="09">09</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="11">11</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="12">12</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="01">01</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="02">02</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="03">03</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="04">04</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="05">05</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="06">06</asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:DropDownList>

                   <asp:DropDownList id="endMinutes" runat="server">
             <asp:ListItem Value="00">00</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="15">15</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="30">30</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="45">45</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

                   <asp:DropDownList id="endAmPm" runat="server">
             <asp:ListItem Value="AM">AM</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="PM">PM</asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:DropDownList>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                </div>
               </table>

                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: that's a good one.

Thank you very much. I am able to verify that it works real good.